# Laravel - How to access Array inside Collection

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get some feeds from online api through Laravel. I have this in my laravel:

```
{
"assetCount,": "96",
"title": "testing",
"description": "Users feedback",
"articles": {
"id": "206",
"publishedTime": "234663266",
"teaser": "*REI and VDC DEC teams to..."
}
}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SmsFeed extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'sms_feeds';

protected $fillable = ['asset_count', 'title', 'description', 'published_time', 'teaser', 'smskey', 'category'];

}
```

The question is, how do I complete articles that is a collection of array.

```
        $array_content=[];

     $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.test.com/monk/1xhxiluh826bt7?_fmt=json&_rt=b&ctg=english%20football%20sms&_fld=tsr,pt&kwd=arsenal");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Important
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

         //$array = json_decode($result, true);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
          curl_close ($ch);
        $plainXML = self::mungXML($result);
    $arrayResult = json_decode(json_encode(SimpleXML_Load_String($plainXML, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA)), true);
    $i=0;


    foreach($arrayResult['monk'] as $value)
    {
        $record=SmsFeed::where('id', $value['articles']['id'])->first();

        if (!isset($record)) {
        SmsFeed::create([
            'sms_key'      => $value['@attributes']['id'],
            'category'     =>  'arsenal',
            'asset_count'  =>   $value['assetCount'],
            'title'     => $value['title']
        ]);
        }

    $i++;            
    }
```

I need help in the foreach statement. How do I complete it for article that has (id, publishedTime, teaser)

Comment: Where is your `article` code?

Comment: I dont know how to complete it

Comment: Do you have an `Article` model and table?